# Can a <table> have border-radius and border properties at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a border-radius and a solid border to a table but the border property seems to cancel out border-radius.  Is this a known issue or am I just messing up?

```
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0;border: 2px solid #000000;
```

Comment: Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2dt1peqo/  using a basic table and that line of css, I could not see the issue you mentioned.  What does your table HTML look like?

Answer (score 5):

I think Your HTML Table Structure is wrong or you can not apply CSS correctly.

Try This:

**HTML**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th>
                Contact
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Nayeem
            </td>
            <td>
                Khulna
            </td>
            <td>
                9812979832
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that seems to work, so I think something is off within my code.

Comment: Yeah, I think so.

Comment: Had border-collapse: collapse in the head.  So think that was breaking it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a container:

```css
.table-container {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then wrap the `<table>`...

```html
<div class='table-container'>
  <table> ... </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly, this is for an HTML email so <div> may cause some issues.

Comment: I've got alot of nested tables so I think that's what is causing the issue.